# How does mongoDB order values when sorting, if the values are the same?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

for instance, if i'm sorting a collection by val in :

```
 `[{id: 1, val: 1}, {id: 2, val: 2} , {id: 3, val: 3}, {id: 4, val: 2}]
```

,  etc.. How does it determine which val of 2 comes first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query is reading the values sorted from an index, the ordering will most likely be inherited from how the documents are stored in the index (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#sort-and-index-use).

For example, if the query is reading the results pre-sorted from the index `{ "val" : 1, "val2" : 1 }`, then the results would likely be sorted by the field "val2".

If documents are being sorted in memory, then results are likely not guaranteed to have a specific order beyond what is specified in the sort clause.